# Makefile compiles unchanged files

Tags: make, g++

Made an effort to get the object files in another directory, but that directory would otherwise reflect the source directory tree. Got that to work, but there is a missing piece at the `$(OBJ):` line (right?), so whether you change the source or not, it recompiles. Have a look.

```
SRC_PATH=../src/
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lSDL -lSDL_gfx
INCL=-I $(SRC_PATH)include/
EXE=run

SRC=$(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)*.cpp $(SRC_PATH)game/*.cpp $(SRC_PATH)player/*.cpp)
OBJ=$(subst ../src, ../obj, $(SRC:.cpp=))
OBJ_O=$(addsuffix .o, $(OBJ))

all: $(SRC) $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ_O) -o $@

$(OBJ):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -o $(addsuffix .o, $@) $(subst ../obj, ../src, $@).cpp

clean:
    rm -rf run $(OBJ_O)
```

**Edit**

This works as intended: does not recompile. Also, is much easier to read without the complicated suffixes back and forth. See answers and comments below.

```
SRC_PATH=../src/
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lSDL -lSDL_gfx
INCL=-I $(SRC_PATH)include/
EXE=run

SRC=$(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)*.cpp $(SRC_PATH)game/*.cpp $(SRC_PATH)player/*.cpp)
OBJ=$(subst ../src, ../obj, $(SRC:.cpp=.o))

all: $(SRC) $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@

../obj/%.o: ../src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf run $(OBJ)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How do you make it not recompile files that are not changed since the last compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems:

First, your OBJ variable does not refer to a list of files that are built. E.g., when you have source files src/a.cpp and src/b.cpp, OBJ will contain obj/a and obj/b. So use OBJ_O instead of OBJ.

Second, your target for building the OBJ files does not give dependencies between the .cpp and .o files. It is a problem that you write your rule for creating the .o files in that way, because you can't give dependency info in that line. I would completely rewrite that rule for creating .o files:

```
../obj/%.o: ../src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -o "$@" "$<"
```

This builds each .o file separately, and each .o file depends on the corresponding .cpp file.

This is a rule for creating a `../obj/**.o` file from every file that matches `../src/**.cpp`.

Comment: @UlrichDangel see my updated post. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: I tried both those (the .cpp.o and the % solution): `make: No rule to make target ../obj/anim.o, needed by run. Stop.`

Comment: @EmanuelBerg oh, I forgot that you don't compile into `../src/`. See my updated answer; the `.cpp.o` rule  format doesn't work in that case.

Comment: **Very impressive**! Mange tak :)

Answer (score 2):

To make it clearer:

The main problem is precicely the line `$(OBJ):`

The problem is that if there is a source file `../src/a.cpp` the variable `OBJ` contains `../obj/a` and the rule `$(OBJ):` means "use the following recipie to build the file `../obj/a`". But that's not what the recipie does! (Instead it creates a file `../obj/a.o`.)

That's why make will always execute that recipie because it is desperate to create the file `../obj/a` as that filename is listed as a depencency in `$(EXE): $(OBJ)`

Comment: I am aware it lacks the dot and suffix. But if I put it there, how do you get the change of suffix (.o -> .cpp) **and** the proper path change? (Now this is done with: `$(subst ../obj, ../src, $@).cpp` - that only works if there is no suffix at all to start with.)

Comment: Your problem is/was that you were using make incorrectly. If any dependency file has a newer timestamp than the target file (or the target file does not exist) a recipie is exectued.

There are many ways to accomplish what you want and the most favourable is Emanuel's. There are implicit rules, or you can make the substitutions inside the recipie, or you simply `touch $@`.

Comment: "Your problem is/was that you were using make incorrectly." Really? :) As I understand it, the way I "fetched" the object files collectively made it difficult (impossible?) to express the corresponding source file as a dependency. Anyway that issue solved itself since there was a much better way to refer to the objects.